# How to use Google Maps Platform SDK for iOS with Xcode project without using storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-maps-sdk-ios, xcode-storyboard

I am trying out my first Xcode iOS project using Swift using Google Maps Platform. I got as far as Step 5 at [Get Started in documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start) I am not given an option to not use storyboard when I create my Xcode Single View Project, so I removed the Main.storyboard file and the Info.plist "Main storyboard base name" setting and the "Main Interface" setting in the target. I wasn't able to find a way to enable ARC. I believe it is automatically enabled.

I only got a black screen when I ran the project in Simulator for iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (3rd generation).

When I set the settings back to use Main.storyboard, it works fine. What is going on with this? Is this bad documentation? I want to be sure I follow the instructions so I don't run into problems later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get black screen because after you stopped using storyboard as your app is confused and doesn't know what is the initial screen to load (the one that has an arrow in storyboard).
you can set it programmatically in AppDelegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let rootViewController = YourInitialViewController()
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.rootViewController = rootViewController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```